# × Error: Invalid hook call - no version problem or multiple react instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

**EDIT
removing the component from the app also got rid of the error**

I'm trying to fetch on first render with the useEffect hook and I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called
inside of the body of a function component.
```

```
 4 | 
   5 | const Students = ({students, setStudents}) => {
   6 | 
>  7 | useEffect(() =>{
   8 |     fetch('http://localhost:5000/students')
   9 |     .then(response => response.json())
  10 |     .then(json => setStudents(json))
```

I've checked the React versions / duplication issue but it seems to be OK so it must be somewhere but I can't see it - this is the component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import NewStudentCard from './NewStudentCard'


function Students ({students, setStudents}){

useEffect(() =>{
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/students')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
}, [])

    return (
        <ul>
            <NewStudentCard/>
        </ul>
        )
    }

export default Students
```

tried to rename the state and set it directly in the component - still get the error

```
import React, {useState ,useEffect } from 'react';
import NewStudentCard from './NewStudentCard'


const Students = () => {
const [pupils, setPupils] = useState([]);

useEffect(() =>{
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/students')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setPupils(json))
}, [pupils])

    return (
        <ul>
            <NewStudentCard/>
        </ul>
        )
    }

export default Students
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. It looks like the code in the question isn't enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is the only code that gets affected - added more code for context

Comment: You're still not showing how you're using the component, and what is the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: edited my question again

Comment: Since you're not showing where and how the `Students` component is used, I can only guess that it's not used correctly in the render cycle, and instead used outside of a component's render or asynchronously, which is equally incorrect with hooks.

Comment: that might be the issue since removing it helps - might have to investigate further, thank you